# How to unit test a callback registered with an event registered using backbone listenTo?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine

I am registering an event with its handler using backbone listenTo/on api. Now how to unit test using jasmine that correct handler is being attached with the event. I can spy listenTo/on and check whether correct eventName is provided as an argument of listenTo/on, but what is the proper way to check proper callback is registered with the event.

**Edit:** Suppose I want to unittest the following statement.

```
if(condition) {
   obj1.on('eventName1', callBack1);
}
else {
   obj1.on('eventName2', callBack2);
}
```

Now, I can spy 'on' and check in jasmine whether it has been called with '*eventName1/eventName2*', but how to check the same for the callback?

Comment: Do add your code so we can at least see what's written so far, and even highlight what's not working.

Comment: @Stuart : example added.

Answer (score 0):

You can spy on the expected candler and check if it has been called after triggering the event.

Comment: But, my purpose of unit testing is to verify whether I have provided proper arguments with the on/listenTo api of backbone. The proper binding of the handler with the event lies in the scope of the implementation of on/listenTo in backbone.js.

Comment: @SubhankarMukherjee This is what you asked *"what is the proper way to check proper callback is registered with the event*". The arguments you provide to `listenTo` is the object you want to listen to and the method of the object you want to invoke. So spying on that method and making sure it's getting called ensures the arguments you provide to `listenTo` were correct. The answer is still valid.